# How to set Listview control column backcolor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a windows form containing a ListView control. I am setting the rows of the listview control with alternating color using the code below:

```
public void SetAlternateColors(ListView lView, Color evenRowColor, Color oddRowColor)
{
    //loop through each ListViewItem in the ListView control
    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lView.Items)
    {
        lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = true;
        if ((lvi.Index % 2) == 0)
            lvi.BackColor = evenRowColor;
        else
            lvi.BackColor = oddRowColor;
    }
}
```

With the listview having alternating row color, now I want to set the backcolor 
of a particular column just like the image shown below. Is it possible to do so in a listview control? Please advise with some codes.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could set it as ListViewItem.SubItem[x].BackColor. For example, if I need to set different colors for first three columns of my ListView, I would do the following.

```
 foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
 {
   item.SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Green;
   item.SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.Blue;
   item.SubItems[2].BackColor = Color.Orange;
   item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
 }
```

Please note you also needs to set  `UseItemStyleForSubItems = false`